# Adding numbers in a list but only after a certain number

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that takes a bowling score.

### The Rules

-If you get a STRIKE you get 10 points plus the next two balls you score.

My question: **Is there a way to add the next two numbers in a list after 10 appears. so far my code just takes the users score and stores it in a list.**

```
def f54():
    total_pins= 10
    max_score= 300
    frames= 20
    count= 1
    score=0
    zval = []
    yval = []

    for i in range(1,11):

        2_ahaed = i+2
        1_ahead = i+1

        z=int(input('What was your score for ball 1 frame ' +str(i)+':'))
        if z != 10:
            y=int(input('What was your score for ball 2 frame ' +str(i)+':'))

        if z > total_pins:
            print('this number is too large, re enter all scores')
            f54()
        if z < 10:
            zval.append(z)
        if z == 10:
            print('Strike!')


        if y > total_pins:
            print('this number is too large, re enter all scores')
            f54()
        if y < 10:
            yval.append(y)
        if y == 10-z:
            print('spare!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with bowling scoring rules but this should do what you are asking:

```
scores = [1,2,10,3,4,5,10,1]

ret = [0 for x in (scores)]

for i in xrange(len(scores)):
        ret[i] = sum(scores[i:i+3]) if scores[i] == 10 else scores[i] 

print "Final score", sum(ret)
```

Comment: What exactly does this code do? It workes to an extent but I'm not sure what it does?

Comment: It takes a list of scores and produce a list ret, if a score is 10 it adds the following two scores otherwise it just copy the score. Then it sums the content of ret to produce the final score.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can. .
List[index:] represents all of the values that comes `After` the given index number. .
List[:index] represents all of the values that comes `Before` the given index number. .

in this Case,

```
zval = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for val in zval:
   if val==7:
     `print zval[val:]`
      print sum(zval[val:])
```